# PHP data sources

Tags: php, database, datasource

I am a java developer thus new to PHP. 
In java we have the concept of data sources where for example we can obtain a connection object to connect to a database.

I know that PHP supports odbc_connect etc.

1. Does PHP support data sources?
2. What are the widely-used frameworks/methods to use data sources or to connect to databases in PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/PDO and http://php.net/ODBC

Comment: So in addition to the direct php support, how are the frameworks like cake php, pear used in the industry? Do they provide any additional support that further ease up the work of php developers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most PHP applications use an SQL database and some form of NoSQL cache. PHP offers great support of SQL databases with the inbuilt `PDO` objects:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

NoSQL options like redis and mongo usually come with either a 3rd party PHP library to provide support, or a 3rd party extension which can be included when you compile PHP for installation.

As discussed, `ODBC` is a database absraction layer which has good documentation in the PHP manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/intro.uodbc.php

Answer (score 2):

Look into PHP's ODBC Abstraction layer:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php

odbc_connect() allows you to connect to the data source, odbc_data_source() returns the information about that data source. The rest of the functions will show you how to interact with the data source.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a few popular extensions for DB querying:

1. MySQL (standard mysql) --> mysql only, no parameterised queries (not used in development anymore)
2. MySQLi (mysql improved version) --> mysql only, with parameterised queries
3. PDO (PHP Data Object) --> any type of db, with parameterised queries

If you want ODBC, here's the one: http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php

Comment: The first one in your list is not  one of the `popular extensions`, in fact it has a very bad reputation and is already deprecated. Please consider removing it. Notice the red box here: http://www.php.net/mysql_query